# Save a random Forest object

Tags: r

I have a randomForest object that I want to save for later use.  I've tried some of the following but with no luck.

```
save(topDawg , file="myRFobject.RData")
```

This just saves a string "topDawg"

```
> formula(topDawg)
Error in formula.default(topDawg) : invalid formula


> save(getTree(topDawg))
Error in save(getTree(topDawg)) : object ‘getTree(topDawg)’ not found
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do here, since normally you `save` an object and then `load` it later, like this:

```
set.seed(71)
> irisrf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris, importance=TRUE,
+                         proximity=TRUE)
> save(irisrf,file = "irisrf.RData")
> 
> rm(irisrf)
> print(irisrf)
Error in print(irisrf) : object 'irisrf' not found
> 
> load("irisrf.RData")
> print(irisrf)

Call:
 randomForest(formula = Species ~ ., data = iris, importance = TRUE,      proximity = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: classification
                     Number of trees: 500
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

        OOB estimate of  error rate: 4.67%
Confusion matrix:
           setosa versicolor virginica class.error
setosa         50          0         0        0.00
versicolor      0         47         3        0.06
virginica       0          4        46        0.08
```

Comment: Very nice trick if you wanna run a r classifier with the subprocess call function in python

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem (loading RandomForest object resulted in character string) and something like this seemed to have worked for me:

```
forest = get(load("forestGOOG.RData"))
```

(I have a random forest object 'forestGOOG' saved in the working directory)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution if you would like to load the model under another name

```
  library(randomForest)

  # 1. Create data set
  set.seed(100)
  df_iris <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data = iris, importance = TRUE,  proximity = TRUE)

  # 2. Save model
  file_name <- "model_iris.rds"
  saveRDS(df_iris, file_name)

  # 2.3. Load model under another name
  df_iris_loaded <- readRDS(file_name)
  df_iris_loaded

  # 2.4. Test two models
  identical(df_iris, df_iris_loaded, ignore.environment = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Once a random forest model is created save the model as a file so that you can reuse it later.

```
#model
  model_rf <- randomForest(y~ ., data = dataset, mtry=7,ntree=500)

#write model
  saveRDS(model_rf , "model_rf.RDS")

#load model
 readRDS("model_rf.RDS")
```