# How to save the forest created in R randomForest for future use

Tags: r, random-forest

Is there a way to save the forest created by randomForest in R for future use? 
This is because in a production environment, one would be using the same model (in this case the forest) for prediction purposes over and over again.

Using the codes below as an example, if `testdata` is not available now for prediction or a new set of `testdata` will be available in the future, running `randomForest()`again will create a different forest (as I understand it).

Any comment is much appreciated.  Thanks.

```
library(randomForest)
data<-data.frame(flag=c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0),
                 v1 = rnorm(10, 3, 1),
                 v2 = rnorm(10, 3, 1),
                 v3 = rnorm(10, 3, 1))

data$flag=as.factor(data$flag)

rf<-randomForest(flag ~ ., data=data)

pred(rf, testdata)  #testdata not yet available or a new set will be available in the future
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save a random Forest object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863942/save-a-random-forest-object)

Comment: i think there is an `keep.forest` in the `randomForest` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save objects in R using `saveRDS` then load them with `readRDS`

```
saveRDS(rf, "mymodel.rds")
rf2 <- readRDS("mymodel.rds")
```

Then in a new session

```
library(randomForest)
data<-data.frame(flag=c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0),
                 v1 = rnorm(10, 3, 1),
                 v2 = rnorm(10, 3, 1),
                 v3 = rnorm(10, 3, 1))

data$flag=as.factor(data$flag)

rf <- readRDS('mymodel.rds')
predict(rf, data)
```

Comment: I tried it.  It works in the same R session.  However, when I run in a new session, I received an error message of `type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data`.  I have checked many times the test data is the same (i.e. factor, int etc).  Did I missed out anything?  Thanks.

Comment: Not sure, did you try passing the exact same dataset?

Comment: Yes, I did check.  They are the same.  I first generated predictions using the test data and I obtained results.  Then I saved the forest using `saveRDS`, exported the test data and closed the session.  In a new session, I restored the forest using  `readRDS` and imported the test data.  But when I tried to generate predictions using the restored forest, it failed.

Comment: Try the code I added above in a new R session, this works for me

Comment: Thanks.  Based on your inputs, I found  the problem.  The test data or validation data cannot have factor variables.  Otherwise, it will fail in a new session (but will work in the same session).  I converted everything to integers/doubles.  It now works.